# Difference between 好点儿了吗 and 好些了吗?

Tags: meaning

Hi I came across both sentences, in both cases meaning "Is STH any better?".
So are they interchangeable and have the same meaning and usage?
I thought 些 is only used with countable words, but in the example I found it was used with 心情, which defintely isn't countable.
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

好點兒了嗎 and 好些了嗎 can be used interchangeably. They are used to ask if something get better. Because 好點 and 好些 share the similar meaning so 好點兒了嗎 and 好些了嗎 can be used interchangeably. Both 好點 and 好些 are used to denote something get better. You can imagine them as if 好點 and 好些 are 變好一點 and 變好一些 respectively. And 一點 and 一些 are used to denote a little amount of quality.